# Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'CACHE_TAG'

Tags: magento-1.9

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'CACHE_TAG' in 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\proj\app\code\local\Web\Customization\Block\product.php
>   on  line 19

```
class Web_Customization_Block_product extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
  public $_productCollection;

  public function _getStore(){
        return Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
  }

  protected function _construct(){

        $collection = Mage::getModel('customization/product')->getCollection()
                      ->addFieldToFilter('store_id' , array ( array( 'finset' => $this->_getStore()) , array( 'eq' => 0)));
        $collection->getSelect()->order('sort_order ASC');
        $this->_productCollection = $collection->getData();

        $this->addData(array(
            'cache_lifetime' => false,
            'cache_tags' => array(Web_Customization_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG)
        ));
  }
   public function getProductSteps(){
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the constant `Web_Customization_Model_Product:CACHE_TAG` does not exist.